# Why is the period of Shovavim connected to tikkun habris?

Tags: sin, repentance-teshuvah, sexuality, shovavim-tat

Please see this [question and answers](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4740/shoivavim-tat-significance) for background information.

What is the reason that the period of Shovavim is used to address tikkun habris (sexual sins)? Why is this time period auspicious for dealing with this sin specifically?

Answer (score 4):

[Nitei Gavriel](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46444&st=&pgnum=415) mentions in the name of the Arizal that since during these weeks we read the portions of the Torah starting from the enslavement in Egypt (where there was Tikun HaKeri of Adam HaRishon) until Ki Tsikne Eved Ivri.