# שובבים and Taharas Hamishpacha

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, niddah, shovavim-tat

As we begin the weeks of Shovavim (the upcoming 6 parshiyos, Shemos through Mishpatim), many of us will notice signs going up all around us for improvement in keeping the Halachos of Niddah ("Taharas Hamishpacha"), and classes available weekly.  My question is what is **the earliest source** linking these two together (i.e. a source that says one should study these topics during these weeks).  Feel free to provide any and all sources.

This question is different than [Why is the period of Shovavim connected to tikkun habris?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22925/why-is-the-period-of-shovavim-connected-to-tikkun-habris), as I am asking for:

- the **earliest source**
- specifically discussing **learning about this** rather than Teshuva or other Tikkunim
- specifics relating to **Taharas Hamishpacha**, not just Tikun Habris in general

Comment: Discussed in this forum https://www.tora-forum.co.il/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=1158 || Quote: מה שברור שמדובר בדבר חדש של השנים האחרונות ממש. No sources there I'm afraid though

Comment: @JoelK great find! Thanks.  It really strengthens the question to know that Hilchos Shabbos is considered a Tikun Habris, which now that I think of it, I think I learned that in the Hakdama to Eglei Tal.  Do you think I should reword the question this way?

Comment: Not sure it’s necessary to re-word the question. Might overcomplicate things. Could ask as a separate question: Does anyone advocate learning hilchos shabbos during shovavim as a tikkun habris? But up to you...

Comment: Also, there seem to be references floating around to the week of va’era being specifically a time for tikkun in niddah which might lead to an answer here. Again, no real source but might be an avenue to research. See eg https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/שובבי%22ם

Comment: @JoelK again, good find, I'll try to follow up on that.

Comment: Is it possible that it comes directly as a remez in ״שובו בנים שובבים״? (That being connected with the aforementioned items)

Answer (score 1):

[Nitei Gavriel Chanuka - Yemei Hashovavaim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46444&st=&pgnum=415&hilite=) quotes the [Be'er Hataiv 685:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=298) that mentions it in the name of the Arizal. The reason given is that Shemos begins the enslavement of the Jews in Egypt which was as a Kapara for the sin of Keri done by Adam HaRishon. Be'er Hataiv says this is for those that fast during these weeks.

[Nitei Gavriel Chanuka - Yemei Hashovavaim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46444&st=&pgnum=420) brings from the Shem M'Shmuel that in the current times one should learn rather than fast.

Therefore, while the earliest source for a Kapparah for Keri is found in the Arizal, the earliest source that I found that suggests learning Torah as a specific Kapparah is the Shem Mishmuel.

I have been unable to find a source that specifically mentions learning about Taharas HaMishpacha.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות: I think my answer clearly says that the Arizal is the source for Kapara for the sin of Keri . If it is unclear to you please edit.