# Judaism and Ping-Pong

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, shabbat, games-toys

I am looking to perhaps write a paper on ping-pong and its place in Torah literature.

I can see a number of issues relating to ping-pong on Shabbos and Yom Tov, e.g., there is a widely discussed Shaila relating to a man playing ping-pong with Ishto Nidah, and even perhaps a discussion as to whether it is appropriate to play ping-pong at all (Bittul Torah etc.)!

So I am interested in any sources in Torah-related literature (Hebrew or English, Shu"t, Peirushim, Halacha Sefarim, etc.) that relate to ping-pong. I have seen some Teshuvos on some of these topics, but I don't currently remember where they are.

Comment: Perhaps you could supply a reason to why you would either think it is permitted or forbidden? Ie. Explaining the premise of your questions

Comment: @ShoelU'Meishiv its essentially a sources question, so I don't think its necessary - I'm not looking for answers to a particular issue, just where I can find ping-pong, no matter what the issue is.

Comment: @ShoelU'Meishiv Leshitascha, for Shabbos-related issues look below, for niddah there are issues of Sechok/Kurvah, as well as Hoshata/Zerika.

Comment: no problem - then is there a need to translate sources?

Comment: @ShoelU'Meishiv not for me, but if in the future someone asks a specific halacha question about this and wants to reference this question, it would help point them in the right direction.  Also, many readers will gain from learning any Torah, so why not let the English speakers learn too?

Comment: i added a source below for nidda

Comment: I dont think bittul torah applies to women. So maybe women should be allowed to, at least in the week.

Comment: Bittul Torah would perhaps prohibit any sports, not just ping pong. OTOH, I think two roshie yeshiva told me, one with a bit of emphasis, actually, that not only does he believe that sports is NOT bittul Torah (in moderation, of course), but he specifically incorporates a sports period into the daily yeshiva schedule. He refers to *Venishmartem Lenfashoteichem* as his source and feels that it is essential that kids get physical exercise each day (gym is about an hour). He also insists that kids must be in the gym doing something physically active, i.e., they should not be "hanging around".

Comment: @DanF so you have answered your own question, this might have some value if considered a "sport" relative to, say, computer games, but might be considered more bittul torah than a real sport, like basketball.  (Well, according to that Rosh Hayeshiva anyways...)

Comment: @רבותמחשבות did you end up finishing this topic? Perhaps you could send the finished essay to Mefaresh@gmail.com

Comment: Doesn't the Shulchan Aruch rule that a ball is muktzeh?  Also https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/playing-games/

Answer (score 7):

- Regarding Shabbos issues: 
  See [here](http://m.shut-halacha.co.il/question_print.php?id=702):

> שאלה:
>
> האם מותר לשחק בשבת פינג פונג שולחן או משחק גולות ?
>
> תשובה:
>
> מותר לשחק גולות בשבת בתוך הבית כיון שהקרקע מרוצפת. כמו כן ניתן להקל
>   לשחק גם בחצר מרוצפת המצורפת לבית. וכן מותר לשחק פינג פונג שולחן בתוך
>   הבית או מחוץ לבית כשיש עירוב. כיון שאין כאן חשש של "לאשויי גומות",
>   דהיינו:ליישר את פני הקרקע). פוסק: הרב יהושע ישעיה נויבירט
>
> ספר: שמירת שבת כהלכתה מהדורה ג' תש"ע
>
> מקור: פרק טז/ סעיף ה (ראה גם הערה יח) וסעיף ו'

And [here](https://www.ynet.co.il/articles/0,7340,L-3936331,00.html):

> שאלה:   האם מותר לשחק פינג פונג בשבת? (דני בר, תל-אביב)   תשובה:   דני
>   שלום וברכה,   במשחק הפינג פונג אין בעצם שום פעולה של איסור הנוגעת
>   לשבת.   אמנם, בשולחן ערוך נאסר לשחק בכדור וזו לשונו: "אסור לשחוק בשבת
>   ויו"ט בכדור". (אורח חיים סימן שח, מה).   הלכה זו נמצאת בתוך סימן העוסק
>   בדיני מוקצה, והאיסור לדעה זו נובע מהעובדה שהכדורים שלהם לא היו ראויים
>   לשימוש, ולכן אין עליהם שם של כלי, ואסורים בטלטול ובמשחק.   אולם הרמ"א
>   כותב על כך: "ויש מתירין, ונהגו להקל". והסביר במשנה ברורה, מכיוון
>   שהכדור מיוחד למשחק, אין עליו שם מוקצה, ומותר בטלטול ובמשחק.   יש
>   מסבירים כי ההבדל בין הפסקים של השולחן ערוך והרמ"א נובע ממציאות שונה של
>   כדורים במקומות הפוסקים, ומכל מקום, בזמננו שהכדורים מיוחדים ועשויים לשם
>   משחק - הם אינם מוקצים ומותר לשחק בהם.   מבחינה זו אין הבדל בין כדור
>   ובין משחק פינג פונג. כל החלקים מיועדים למשחק, לכן אינם מוקצים ומותר
>   לשחק בהם.   לפי זה, כל משחקי כדור יהיו מותרים, מלבד כדורגל, שבו יש
>   בעיה אם משחקים על גבי דשא או קרקע שאינה מרוצפת.   כך גם פוסק בשמירת
>   שבת כהלכתה: "אין לאסור משחקי כדור, להוציא משחק כדורגל... והוא הדין
>   לגבי משחק פינג פונג". (פרק טז, ו)   **משחקים בשבת אמנם, יש להעיר באופן
>   כללי לגבי המשחקים בשבת, על פי הנאמר במדרש ובתלמוד הירושלמי, שהייתה 
>   עיר אחת שנענשה בגלל שהיו משחקים בה בכדור בשבת** (הובאו הדברים בערוך
>   השולחן אורח חיים סימן שח). האחרונים הסבירו מדרש זה, שגם לפי השיטה שאין
>   איסור לשחק בכדור, הם נענשו משום שזה היה עיקר עיסוקם בשבת, במקום לעסוק
>   בתוכן הרוחני של השבת (תפילה, לימוד, משפחה וכו').   בזה נוגעים בכלל
>   גדול בתורה הצריך ביאור נפרד, והוא - רוח ההלכה. כלומר, גם דברים המותרים
>   – לפעמים נוגדים את רוח ההלכה וצריך להימנע מהם.   לכן, גם בנושא משחק
>   הפינג פונג, מותר לשחק בו בשבת בזמן מוגבל, אולם צריך להיזהר שהמשחק לא
>   יהיה עיקר השבת הן מבחינת הזמן והן מבחינת חשיבותו. כל טוב (משיב: הרב
>   שמואל שפירא, רבה של כוכב יאיר)

And [here](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/7624) as well.

- Regarding Nidda Issues see [here](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%97%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%95_%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%94) as well:

> ומשחק פינג-פונג – עי' שו"ת משנה הלכות ח"ה סי' קנ שהחמיר בזה בניגוד
>   לדעת הבאר משה (רבי משה שטרן זצ"ל מדערבצין) ח"??? סי' מט אות ה

[Rav Moshe Heineman](https://www.star-k.org/images/publication-halachos-niddah.pdf) permits playing ping pong with ones wife when she is in Niddah, nevertheless he warns against it become קלות ראש:

> לשחק משחק "פינג-פונג" וכדומה, לית ביה משום הושטה,
>
> אמנם פעמים דיש בו משום קלות ראש

He quotes the Be’er Moshe:

> ט. עי' בשו''ת באר משה )ח''א סי' נ' אות ה'( מש''כ דאין לאסור זה כיון
>   דמתחלה צריך הכדור שיגע בשלחן קודם שיגע אל מי שכנגדו.

However Rav Heineman adds that even without that sevara it would be permitted, as the whole point of the game is for the other person to *not* catch the ball:

> אמנם למעשה נראה  דבלא''ה פשוט דמותר, כיון דכוונת המשחק הוא דוקא שלא 
>   יקבל האחר הכדור

Comment: Shkoyach for these sources! +1. If you come across anything else, such as anything published in a Jewish book, please feel free to add it to your answer.  This set of Teshuvos gives me a valuable source, the Shemiras Shabbos (16:6).

Comment: @רבותמחשבות it is very Kdai to see inside the kuntres of Rav Heineman i linked to

Comment: it looks very interesting!  Funny that it was published during shovevim - see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88161/שובבים-and-taharas-hamishpacha

Comment: It would help most of our readers if you could summarize the quotes into English. IMO, the 2nd citing could be significantly trimmed and summarized - even the Hebrew.

Answer (score 3):

On whether it is appropriate to play ping-pong (table tennis) on Shabbat [dinonline](http://dinonline.org/2011/08/14/ping-pong-table-tennis-on-shabbos/) writes

> There is no formal prohibition on ping pong. Although the Shulchan
>   Aruch (308:45) mentions a blanket prohibition on ball games, this is
>   based on the prohibition of mukzeh, and balls such as ping pong balls,
>   which are clearly designated for games, are not muktzeh (based on
>   Rema, loc. cit. and Mishnah Berurah). With the exception of football
>   (meaning soccer, in particular on grass), ball games are therefore
>   permitted, including ping pong (Shemiras Shabbos Kehilchasah 16:6).
>
> However, as a general rule one should not spend Shabbos playing games,
>   but focus rather on spiritual pursuits (davening, learning Torah,
>   meals infused with Torah and spiritual content). See Aruch Hashulchan
>   (308) who mentions a Midrash concerning a place that was destroyed
>   because of the neglect of this idea.
>
> Therefore, although permitted, games such as ping pong should not be a
>   principle part of a person’s Shabbos experience.

[torah.org](https://torah.org/torah-portion/weekly-halacha-5767-kisavo/) writes it is allowed according to all views (cf. point 13).

See also [JemSem](http://jemsem.org/adar-i-5760-ping-pong-on-shabbos/) which writes it is permitted but discusses whether it is a appropriate with a cute story of learning Torah while waiting to play.

Comment: Very clear sources - though how does this add to the answer I provided above? (I upvoted you by the way) this answer is based on the Shmiras Shabbos (which I quoted)

Comment: @ShoelU'Meishiv it is pretty much the same answer, translated into english, with no new sources, but the other two articles are helpful.  Fn 13 (not fn 12) is an addition to this discussion.

Comment: @mbloch thats good enough for me :) god forbid - not a competition - though קנאת סופרים תרבה חכמה