# The Arizal and Shovavim

Tags: history, sexuality, provenance, arizal, shovavim-tat

This week begins the six week period of [Shovavim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shovavim), a time period that the Arizal wrote is an auspicious time to work on oneself, especially in the areas of sexual transgressions.

I have two questions:

1. Is the Arizal the originator of this idea? Or did he already have a Mesorah for it? If so, what is the earliest source for this idea
2. If the Arizal was the originator of this idea, is it historically documented that the people who lived during his time period struggled particularly with sexual sins?

Comment: It can't be that old as Parshat Bo wasn't a universal thing. Some communities used to have Parshat Hashkem instead.

Comment: @DoubleAA Or Parshat Pharaoh, as the Tanya Rabbati and Machzor Romi call Bo. Then again, they both refer to Vaera as Re'eh, so you don't even need to get to Bo.

Comment: The answer here quotes R. Chaim Vital as calling Shovavim an ancient tradition: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4750/3388

Comment: @chaim I mean the parsha break was in a different place namely before Barad. Not just a different name.

Comment: @DoubleAA very interesting. Do you have source on hand?